# Quicksort partitioning

Tags: sorting, quicksort, partitioning, partition

I am sorry to be dumb, but I have been struggling with my own quicksort implementation for quiet a while. To be more specific, I can't get my partition procedure to work properly. Ridiculously enough, but I've also tried to almost directly copy an implementation from Sedjewick's book, with no success, however.
Here is my code:

```
void partition(int a[], int size)
{
    int i, j = size - 1;
    int t, pivot = a[j / 2];
    i = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (a[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        t = a[i];
        a[i++] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
}
```

Here is the example of input:

```
82, 65, 59, 10, 35, 51, 81, 47, 25, 64, 34, 38, 12, 38, 58, 74, 37, 42, 63, 18,
75, 67, 36, 77, 47, 48, 13, 91, 94, 52
```

The pivot here is 58, but I get wrong output:

```
52, 13, 48, 10, 35, 51, 47, 47, 25, 36, 34, 38, 12, 38, 18, 58, 37, 42, 63, 74,
75, 67, 64, 77, 81, 59, 65, 91, 94, 82
```

It looks *almost* correct, with a little exception of 37 and 42 going right after 58. I've tried a lot of variations of partitioning procedure, but they all get me similar results.

Comment: Without doing a detailed analysis, two points come to mind: What if a[i] or a[j] == pivot? One of those should still cause a swap. Also, you increment i in the middle of your swap, but don't decrement j. Shouldn't they be symmetric?

Comment: mpez0, If a[i] or a[j] equal pivot, they will be swapped anyways. I believe there is nothing stopping thins from happening in my code. As for the lack of j decrement, I don't see how it can cause any damage, but making j decrease each iteration doesn't help the situation. The result gets a bit different (there are two numbers which are bigger than 58 on the left site), but it is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

My previous answer seemed to fix the issue but wasn't correct.

Your output is fine. Let me visually indicate the partition with vertical bars:

52, 13, 48, 10, 35, 51, 47, 47, 25, 36, 34, 38, 12, 38, 18, 58, 37, 42 || 63, 74, 75, 67, 64, 77, 81, 59, 65, 91, 94, 82

Everything to the left of the vertical bars is <= 58, and everything to the right is >= 58. This is what's expected from the partition step in a quicksort.

You do, however, need to decrement `j` in addition to incrementing `i`:

```
t = a[i];
a[i++] = a[j];
a[j--] = t; // added a decrement here
```

Other than that, the only thing you're missing is returning the partition index. Simply return the value of `i` at the end of the function and use that as the array boundary in your recursive step.

Comment: It gets looped if a[i] both a[j] equal pivot, as neither of while-cycles continues to increase i or j.

Comment: I could have added a one more if case and the code would probably work, but that doesn't sound really efficient.

Comment: @J.Doe See my edit. I had forgotten how quicksort is supposed to work. :-) Your existing code is actually fine!

Comment: Interesting, looks like I misunderstood the concept of partitioning a bit. As for not returning a  value, that was intended for testing purposes.

Comment: Oh, one more edit. I think the change I suggested (decrementing `j`) is actually necessary for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `a[j] = t;` with `a[j--] = t`

Comment: I think you are confusing i++ with ++i. i++ returns i.

Comment: yeah, realised that and other mistake too from smarx's answer.  :)